# How to implement extension method yielding two results for each input value?

Tags: c#, yield-return

I am currently building an extension method which processes an `IEnumerable<TSource>`. For each item in the source collection I need to yield one or two items of the resulting type.

This is my first approach, which fails, since the method is being left on the first return statement, and forgets about its state when the second return statement is being hit.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> DoSomething<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    where TResult : new()
{
    foreach(item in source)
    {
        if (item.SomeSpecialCondition)
        {
            yield return new TResult();
        }
        yield return new TResult();
    }
}
```

How would I implement this scenario correctly?

Comment: I don't see why that doesn't work... I must be misunderstanding.

Comment: Yeah, I actually tested it on a trivial example and it works.

Comment: `DoSomething<TSource, TResult>` and `foreach(var item in source)`. Everything else is ok.

Comment: I don't see any problems, but for one iteration can be two items yielded, so there is a possibility that the number of items isn't the same.

Comment: Hmpf. I will try to create an example demonstrating the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution should work. Here is a full sample program which demonstrates that approach working:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        void run()
        {
            var test = DuplicateOddNumbers(Enumerable.Range(1, 10));

            foreach (var n in test)
                Console.WriteLine(n);
        }

        public IEnumerable<int> DuplicateOddNumbers(IEnumerable<int> sequence)
        {
            foreach (int n in sequence)
            {
                if ((n & 1) == 1)
                    yield return n;

                yield return n;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, note Dmitry Dovgopoly's comment about using the correct TSource and TResult.

Comment: You are right - I obviously missed something in my first ("slightly" more complicated) implementation...